# Segmentation fault - Two functions don't run simultaneously

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have the following code for my program

```
int main(void)
{
    int i,size;
    float vel_x[size],vel_y[size],vel_x0[size],vel_y0[size],rho[size],rho0[size];
    float *ux, *vy, *ux0, *vy0;
    float *r, *r0;
    struct fdparam fdparam_1;

    printf("Enter the number of grid points: \t");
    scanf("%d", &fdparam_1.N);
    printf("Enter the maximum number of iterations: \t");
    scanf("%d", &fdparam_1.MAXIT);
    printf("Enter the value for time domain: \t");
    scanf("%f", &fdparam_1.t_domain);
    printf("Enter the time step and density of the fluid: \t \t");
    scanf("%f\t%f", &fdparam_1.Dt, &fdparam_1.dens);
    printf("Enter the diffusion coefficient and viscosity: \t \t");
    scanf("%f\t%f",&fdparam_1.diff, &fdparam_1.mu);
    printf("The parameters are N=%d, MAXIT=%d, t_domain=%f, Dt=%f, diff=%e, mu=%e, dens=%f \n",fdparam_1.N, fdparam_1.MAXIT, fdparam_1.t_domain, fdparam_1.Dt, fdparam_1.diff, fdparam_1.mu, fdparam_1.dens);

    size=(fdparam_1.N+2)*(fdparam_1.N+2);
    printf("The size is %d \n",size );

    r  = (float*) calloc (size,sizeof(float));
    r0 = (float*) calloc (size,sizeof(float));
    ux = (float*) calloc (size,sizeof(float));
    vy = (float*) calloc (size,sizeof(float));
    ux0 = (float*)calloc (size,sizeof(float));
    vy0 = (float*)calloc (size,sizeof(float));

    var_init(fdparam_1.N,r0,ux0,vy0,fdparam_1.dens);

//      t=0;    
//      Solver functions
//      while (t<fdparam_1.t_domain){
      velocity_solve(fdparam_1.N,ux,vy,ux0,vy0,fdparam_1.Dt,fdparam_1.mu,fdparam_1.MAXIT);    //calculates ux and vy to be used in the density solver
    density_solve(fdparam_1.N,r,r0,ux,vy,fdparam_1.Dt,fdparam_1.diff,fdparam_1.MAXIT);      //uses ux and vy calculated from Navier Stokes in the velocity solver to calculate density r
//      t+=fdparam_1.Dt
//      }
}

    //velocity solver function

    void velocity_solve(int n, float *u, float *v, float *u0, float *v0, float dt, float m, int MAXITER)
{
    int i,j;

    add_source(n,u,u0,dt);          add_source(n,v,v0,dt);
    swap(u0,u);     swap(v0,v);
    diffusion(n,u,u0,dt,m,MAXITER);         diffusion(n,v,v0,dt,m,MAXITER);
    projection(n,u,v,u0,v0,MAXITER);
    swap(u0,u);     swap(v0,v);
    advection(n,u,u0,u0,v0,dt);     advection(n,v,v0,u0,v0,dt);
    projection(n,u,v,u0,v0,MAXITER);

    printf("Printing velocities now \n");
    for (i=0; i<=n+1; i++){
            for (j=0;j<=n+1;j++){
                    printf("%f \t %f \n",u[ix(i,j)],v[ix(i,j)]);
            }
    }
}

// density solver function

void density_solve(int n, float *x, float *x0,  float *u, float *v, float dt, float diff, int MAXITER)
{
    int i,j;

    add_source(n,x,x0,dt);
    swap(x0,x);
    diffusion(n,x,x0,dt,diff,MAXITER);
    swap(x0,x);
    advection(n,x,x0,u,v,dt);

    printf("Printing density now \n");
    for (i=0;i<=n+1;i++){
            for (j=0; j<=n+1;j++){
                    printf("%f \t",x[ix(i,j)]);
            }
    }
    printf("\n");

}
```

The main problem that I am facing while executing this code is that I get a segmentation fault when I try to run both the functions `velocity_solve` and `density_solve` together. The two functions are executed properly when they are run individually i.e. when I comment `velocity_solve`, `density_solve` runs fine and vice-versa.

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong with the functions being used in the `velocity_solve` and `density_solve` routines because neither of the two routines would give individual outputs. I suspect there is something going wrong when the two functions are supposed to interact, i.e the output of `velocity_solve` needs to be used in `density_solve`.

I tried initializing the size variable but then it doesn't make a difference at all. But then I realized that I do not use the arrays that are defined so I commented them out, instead I use the pointers for which I have already allocated memory, then why does it still give a segmentation fault when I try to call both the functions together in main function?

Can someone suggest what is going wrong in the code?

Answer (score 6):

You don't initialize `size`, therefore its value will be *indeterminate* and you will have *undefined behavior* when you use it to create your arrays.

Undefined behavior makes your whole program ill-formed.

Answer (score 3):

In your code, `size` is a local variable of type `auto` storage. Unless initialized explicitly, it will have garbage or *indeterminate* value, making use of which like

```
float vel_x[size];
```

invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related : From `C11` standard, chapter 6.2.4, *"Storage durations of objects"*,

Paragraph 5:

> An object whose identifier is declared with no linkage and without the storage-class specifier `static` has *automatic storage duration,* ...

and Paragraph 6:

> ...The initial value of the object is indeterminate. ...

Also, from the same document, chapter §6.7.9, *"Initialization"*, paragraph 10

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.

and finally, from appendix J.2, *"Undefined behavior"*

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate

Comment: Okay...I get the point...So now how do I initialize this variable size? Because size is later what I have defined.

Comment: @SnehaChoudhury simply move your `float` array definitions after you calculate `size`. That'll solve the issue.

Comment: doesn't work still!! I still get a segmentation fault after the velocity_solve is executed...which means it doesn't execute the density_solve anymore. I realize that I do not use the arrays anywhere but I use the pointers rather, so I tried commenting out the array declaration as well...that does not help either. Any idea what else could be going wrong?